# Why does the determinant of $(A- \lambda I) $ give its eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

[image]

In question 6, why does determinant of $(A- \lambda I)$ gives its eigenvector ?

Comment: OK. Maybe you should watch 3Blue1Brown's "Essence of Linear Algebra" series. In that series, Grant gives visual representation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: @DarkKnight I have watched through that a couple of times, and it is a very good series. But he doesn't address this. I seem to recall him spending _minimal_ time on transposes in general.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take $A-1I$ as an example.

We know, from the fact that $\lambda = 1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, that $A$ is singular, i.e. it has non-trivial nullspace. Here is a useful general fact:

> The nullspace of a matrix $M$ is orthogonal to the column space of $M^T$.

Once we have this fact, it is clear to see what they are doing: They have taken the second and third columns of $(A - I)^T$ (it's not really important *which* columns we pick, as long as they're linearly independent; the $\lambda = 3$ example picks columns 1 and 2) and they calculate the cross product of those two columns using a standard "determinant" mnemonic. This gives a vector which is orthogonal to both the columns. Since we know the column space of $(A-I)^T$ has dimension $2$ (it is a singular $3\times 3$ matrix, but the columns aren't multiples of one another, so the rank isn't $1$ or $0$), a vector which is orthogonal to those two must be orthogonal to all of the column space of $(A-I)^T$, and it must therefore be contained in the 1-dimensional nullspace of $A-I$.

So, why is this fact true? Well, let's take an arbitrary vector $v$ in the nullspace of $M$, and an arbitrary vector $M^Tw$ in the column space of $M^T$. Their dot product, $v^TM^Tw$, is a $1\times 1$ matrix, which is therefore symmetric. Which is to say, we can transpose it without changing the value:
$$
v^TM^Tw = (v^TM^Tw)^T = w^TMv = w^T(Mv) = w^T0 = 0
$$
so $v$ and $M^Tw$ are orthogonal, which is what we wanted to prove.

Comment: Good theory. But your answer doesn't explain how are calculated the second and third rows of the determinants. Therefore doesn't answer the OP question.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes, it does. Haven't you used "determinants" to calculate cross products before? You put the standard basis vectors in the top row, and the two vectors you want to take the cross product of as the second and third row, and then you calculate the determinant of the resulting "matrix" to get a linear combination of the basis vectors. It's a standard mnemonic.

Comment: That is not my point. My point is why are the rows $(10, -8, 10)$ and $(7,-5,7)$ for the first determinant and $(-2,0,0)$ and $(10,-10,10)$ for the second one? I know the answer. But without explaining that, I doubt that the OP will understand the solution provided in the image.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net And will you be happy if I add a clarification like "You can choose whichever two columns of $(A-\lambda I)^T$ you want when you take the cross product, as long as they are linearly independent"?

Comment: Yes that would make sense! Now without quibbling too much, do you really think that working in the dual space, selecting linearly independent columns (the student needs to understand how), building a "mnemonic determinant" is a valuable way to teach students how to find eigenvectors?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net As I mentioned before, we are not here to make judgements on whether the technique in the screenshots is a good technique. We are asked to explain how it works. But that being said, yes, I agree that it is _way_ too theoretically heavy for an introductory student to be expected to reason about it. They can learn the method (going through the motions isn't too difficult), but I don't think it's a good _first_ method for furthering understanding. As an additional "bonus", it only works for $3\times 3$ matrices with eigenvalues of multiplicity $1$.

Comment: (I would personally prefer it if this method, as specialized as it is, were demonstrated once in a later exercise, and the student asked to reason why it works. Then never speak of it again.)

Answer (score 1):

Start from the eigenvalue problem: we look for $\vec{v}, \lambda$ such that

$$A \vec{v} = \lambda \vec{v} = \lambda I \vec{v}$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix. Gathering things on the left hand side, we are trying to solve

$$(A - \lambda I) \vec{v} = 0$$

but we aren't interested in the "trivial" solution $\vec{v}=0$. If the matrix $(A - \lambda I)$ is invertible, then we can multiply by its inverse on both sides and we just get $\vec{v}=0$. A matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is not equal to $0$. So we are looking specifically for the case that

$$\det(A - \lambda I)=0$$

to find the eigenvalues of $A$.

Answer (score -1):

The roots of the equation $\det(A-xI)=0$ are the **eigenvalues**, not the **eigenvectors**. This is like so because for a root $\lambda$ of this equation, the linear application $v \mapsto A-\lambda I$ is not injective, i.e. its kernel is not reduced to the zero vector.

Then for a given eigenvalue $\alpha$, the non-zero vectors $v$ for which $(A-\alpha I)v=0$ are the eigenvectors associated to the eigenvalue $\alpha$.

Comment: i know that but in second screenshot you can see determinant of two rows is the eigenvector ?

Comment: Have you looked at the calculations in the given pictures? They calculate the $\lambda=1$ eigenvector by swapping the first row of $A-1I$ with $(\mathbf{i},\mathbf{j},\mathbf{k})$, and calculate the "determinant".

Comment: I saw. Swapping the first raw with $\mathbf i, \mathbf j, \mathbf k$. And it seems that they compute those values by computing the opposite $2 \times 2$ determinants. This could make sense as the first equation is $v_1=v_1$ for $\lambda=1$. Then for $\lambda=3$ it seems even more complicated... I don’t know why they complicate things that are simple! Just write the equations fulfilled by an eigenvector and solve those... it is that simple!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Straight-forward calculation is simpler than solving equations, even though the equations aren't _that_ difficult. Also, there is some interesting theory behind why this calculation works. For $\lambda = 3$, they are swapping out the _second_ row instead (and then exchanging the top two rows for some reason). Also, this question doesn't ask you to pass judgement on whether the approach is a good one, it's asking you how it works. And your answer fails to address that.

Comment: @Arthur There are some elements of truth in your comments. But not all. Let me remember that the question of the OP is *In question 6, why does determinant of (A−λI) gives its eigenvector ?*. Not saying that the background of the question is in a picture... what is in the picture **is not** the determinant of $A-\lambda I$!

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Yes, a full answer to the question will be pedantic about the choice of words by a clearly inexperienced asker, rather than actually trying to see what they are obviously _trying_ to ask and address that. You're right.